# Controlling AC motor with TRIAC or relay?

Tags: arduino, relay, triac

I have an old Marklin crane that uses two 16V AC motors for rotating left/right and raise/lower the hook.
Using an Arduino, an HC11AA1 for Zero-Cross detection and a TRIAC (BT137 driven by a MOC3052), I can use a knockoff Nunchuck to speed control one of the motors in one direction - All well and good.
Now, I need to control the motor in the opposite direction as well as the other motor in both directions. As I see it, I have two options:
1) Control three more TRIACS
2) Use three relays (one for switching between up/down and left/right and one each for up/down and left/right) to distribute the signal from the first TRIAC
The price is roughly the same, but do you see any pros and/or cons of the two options?

Comment: And what exactly this 16V AC motor? As you are reversing direction?

Comment: The two motors are identical: Two wires for directions and a common 0. Other than that I have no specs for the motors as they are part of the kit.

Comment: Go with three relays. No messing with zero-cross, etc., and easy to debug.

Comment: The OP requires individual speed control for motors. No way using relays.

Comment: I do need zero-cross to do speed control. The question was weather to do individual controls of each motor or 'distribute' the signal via relays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution (maybe with fewer components): Two TRIACs for individual speed control. Two relays for individual direction reversing. Warning: To avoid problems, the TRIAC must be off and the corresponding motor physically stopped in order to reverse its direction.

[image: Sketch by Dirceu Rodrigues Jr]